# Can I change tickers in a plot to custom text tickers?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to change the x-axis on a plot to get ordinal text values and I'm having a hard time trying to find a workaround. Here is my goal: I want to show the IRR of 2 proposed modifications of a government program for the retirees who had middle incomes of 20 000$ and 50 000$ in their whole life.

So, I have 4 IRR: 2 for the ones with 20 000$, and 2 for the ones with 50 000$. What's tricky is that I don't have exact x-coordinates; instead, I used nominal x-coordinates to build my histogram bins (using .quad() method).

Then, using the FixedTicker class, I got only 2 tickers to show: the ones that sit between the bins describing each revenue category. At this point, I'm doing this hoping that I can change these fixed tickers to some other custom tickers (maybe using a dict?), but I really don't know.

I'm guessing here, so maybe I'm completey wrong with this FixedTicker strategy. Is there actually a way to modify tickers? If not, is there any other way?

I tried to use categories on the x-axis, but the problem was that I don't have pairs like category:value, it's more like category:(value, value).

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import FixedTicker

output_notebook()

irr_fed  = [4.24, 3.04]
irr_prov = [2.59, 2.83]

plot = figure(title="Internal Rates of Return: Federal vs. Provincial",
       y_range=(0,5), x_range=(0,12))

plot.quad(top=[irr_fed[0], irr_prov[0], irr_fed[1], irr_prov[1]], bottom=0,
          left=[1,3.5,7,9.5], right=[2.5,5,8.5,11])

plot.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[3, 9])

show(plot)
```

I'd show the plot I get here, but I can't publish images yet, since I'm new here and I don't have enough reputation. If you want to see it, the code works fine in Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably useful to draw out the distinction between a `Ticker` and `TickeFormatter`. The former chooses *where* to put ticks, based on the actual `start` and `end` of a plot range. The latter controls how those ticks are displayed. It sounds like you want to control the *appearance* of the ticks more than anything else, i.e. you want to display some normalized coordinates somehow differently. This suggests you want a custom `TickFormatter` to format your fixed ticks.

In particular, you  might look at the [`FuncTickFormatter`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.FuncTickFormatter) which lets you supply a line or snippet of JS to control the formatting of the tick, arbitrarily. Here is an example:

```
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter, FixedTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file("formatter.html")

p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500, x_range=(0,10))
p.circle([3, 9], [4, 8], size=30)

p.xaxis.ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[3, 9])
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    var mapping = {3: "$20 000", 9: "$50 000"};
    return mapping[tick];
""")

show(p)
```

Which generates this image:

[image]

Depending on your needs you may want to set the `Grid` ticker to also be the same fixed ticker (so that the grid lines match up to the ticks) or just disable to x-grid.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for! There's a problem though, and even when I copy exactly your code, it outputs a blank page. When I erase the JS part, then it works. I haven't gone through JS courses yet, so that's why I'm having a hard time finding what's wrong.

Here is what I see in the console (I had to cut some parts to get it in) :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var(…)
POST http://localhost:8888/jsnlog.logger 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Well, after some reading in bokeh docs, I tried to add a line and it worked. I edited your answer.

Comment: Hi,  the way it is above in is the correct way for `0.12.3` and any future releases. If you upgrade to `0.12.3` or newer you will need change to that way, just FYI

Comment: Correction: this change *will* be in the upcoming `0.12.4` release.