# Bokeh Heatmap - X-Axis ticks mapping

Tags: bokeh, heatmap

I create a heatmap with a large number of indexes --> round_price (300.0, 400.0 , ...)

```html
    round_price 40.0    50.0    60.0    70.0    80.0    100.0
0   300.0   NaN 5.39    34.95   2.31    NaN NaN
1   400.0   NaN 235.89  1959.11 14.48   NaN NaN
2   500.0   2.65    601.68  4558.45 12.21   NaN NaN
3   600.0   NaN 630.54  6688.09 7.69    NaN NaN
4   700.0   NaN 777.61  7253.39 2.59    NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
181 18400.0 NaN 10.16   203.36  NaN NaN NaN
182 18500.0 NaN 5.02    179.38  NaN NaN NaN
183 18600.0 NaN 4.99    129.61  NaN NaN NaN
184 18700.0 NaN NaN 171.14  NaN NaN NaN
185 18800.0 NaN 5.21    104.16  NaN NaN NaN
```

As a result all these round prices are displayed on the x-axis and they are unreadable because they overlap. Thats why I just want to display every tenth tick label on the x-axis.
Now I try to reduce the number of ticks, but it is impossible to me because it is needed to assign the data to the rect. It is difficult to do that because it needs to be a string therefore.
I also dont want to change the orientation of the labels. It will still be not readable because it is to small.

Can you please give me a hint how I can format the x-Axis and make it readable?

Code:

```
from bokeh.models import BasicTicker, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper, PrintfTickFormatter, Range1d, FixedTicker, NumeralTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import components, file_html
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, gridplot
from math import pi

data = pa_df_grouped_p.copy()

data['round_price'] = data['round_price'].astype(str)
data = data.set_index('round_price')
data.columns.name = 'Data'

price = list(data.index)
columns = list(data.columns)

# reshape to 1D array or rates with a month and year for each row.
df = pd.DataFrame(data.stack(), columns=['rate']).reset_index()

# this is the colormap from the original NYTimes plot
colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df.rate.min(), high=df.rate.max())

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="Diamonds",
           x_range=price, y_range=list(reversed(columns)),
           x_axis_location="above", plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
           tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('rate', '@rate%')])

p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "7px"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3

p.rect(x="round_price", y="Data", width=1, height=1,
       source=df,
       fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color=None)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="7px",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                     formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d"),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

show(p)      # show the plot

html = file_html(p, CDN, "my plot1")

# display this html
displayHTML(html)
```

[image]

Best Regards
Ludo

Comment: Went are you using categorical (string) coordinates in the first place? Controlling the ticks will be much simpler if you just use numeric coordinates.

Comment: Hey,
Yes I already tried to use numeric coordinates.
But then I had the problem that figure() expects an array of strings. So I got the error: ValueError: Unrecognized range input: '[300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, ...]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Can I change tickers in a plot to custom text tickers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453228/can-i-change-tickers-in-a-plot-to-custom-text-tickers). I've been having the exact same problem and I have arrived at this solution (even though it is not very clean). Write a helper method to create the necessary JavaScript code for the "FuncTickFormatter" method and you should be good.